# How can I make a progressive login-rate throttle in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, throttling

I'm working on a Django/DRF app, and I'm trying to implement an API throttle that will have an increasingly-long delay for failed login attempts.

Eg. lock the user out for 1 minute after 3 failed attempts, 10 minutes after 6 fails, 30 minutes after 9, etc., similar to what phones do and to what is fairly common to login pages in general.  I was surprised to find that there doesn't appear to be a progressive throttle already built in to Django or DRF given how common that login scenario is...

### DRF Throttle option:

The Django Rest Framework `APIView` provides a `throttle_classes` field & a `get_throttles()` method, and it has a handful of general throttles for doing a *fixed-rate* throttle delay.  I can kind-of mimic a progressive rate by adding a list of throttles, like so:

```
def get_throttles(self):
    return [
        MyCustomThrottle('3/m'),
        MyCustomThrottle('6/10m'),
        MyCustomThrottle('9/30m'),
    ]
```

and then add a custom `get_cache_key()` method to `MyCustomThrottle` that returns a unique key that doesn't collide with the other throttles in the list.

That almost works - it works for blocking a bot that just has its foot on the gas - however, it has a couple of problems:

1. DRF throttles don't have an easy way of *clearing* the throttle list if/when the user logs in successfully.  I've kind-of hacked my way around that by manually modifying the cache that the DRF throttles use, but that's not ideal...
2. DRF throttles are triggered at a certain point in the request loop, and authentication may or may not have happened by that point - so the throttles may not know if the incoming credentials are good:

   A. If doing authentication via the `APIView.authentication_classes` field, then auth happens before throttles, then the throttles can know if auth was successful & can act accordingly.  That has the downside that every bot request will result in a DB hit.

   B. If doing auth in the view code, then auth happens *after* throttles are triggered.  The downside there is that throttles don't know if the incoming creds are good, but the upside is that bots are blocked before the DB is hit.

Our app is doing option B since we're also implementing 2FA (maybe there's a way to do 2FA via `authentication_classes`, but it is what it is today...) and because we want bots to be blocked with minimal DB pummeling.  **Option B kinda rules out DRF throttles since the edge cases cause a crappy/confusing UX.**

### Other options:

I've started looking at [django-axes](https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes) as an alternative to DRF throttles.

**Upsides:**

1. It appears to be more auth-focussed & built from the ground up with auth in mind. It implements throttling via middleware, so it is auth-friendly regardless of where/when auth happens.
2. It provides an easy way to clear throttles on a user, IP, or general-basis.

**Downsides:**

1. It doesn't appear to have a way to provide multiple throttles for a progressive/increasing throttle delay like I'm shooting for.
2. It's mostly designed as a "lock the user out until manually cleared" library.  It does have an option to provide a "cooloff" time to have it automatically unlocked, but it doesn't report, to the user, how much cooloff time is left (like DRF does), nor does it provide an easy way for *me* to provide that info to the user (maybe it does - I'm still kinda new with this library).
3. It appears to have just one set of config options for the entire app - no view-specific config.  We have 2 login pages for 2 types of users.  Each has different throttling needs.

Maybe there's a way I can make django-axes work but, regardless, **I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel here...** Progressive throttling is pretty common in the login world, but it seems to be completely *absent* in the Django world...

**Is there something simple that I'm missing?**  It seems that something like this should already be built into Django/DRF somewhere...

Comment: comming back to my answer after few months, please not that, implementing this at the Firewall level is better idea, for example setting limit in Nginx https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/ rather than allowing bad traffic to hit app server.

Answer (score 1):

### BotBouncer.py - Stop those headless machines

This is my personal library i use for framework agnostic rate limiting, works for Flask, FastAPI, Django. planning to publish to official pypy repository for `pip install botbouncer`. feedback is appreciated.

---

### Setup

> `pip install expiringdict`

---

### Code

```
from expiringdict import ExpiringDict

BOUNCERS = {}
THROTTLE_CONDITIONS = [
    "3/m",
    "6/10m",
    "10/30m"
]


def init_bouncers(defs: list):
    # input[list]: "3/m", "6/10m" , "10/30m"
    # format: n/t -> (n attempts)/(t window)
    global BOUNCERS
    tmap = {
        'm': 60,
        'h': 3600,
        'd': 86400,
        'w': 604800,
        'y': 31536000
    }

    for d in defs:
        n, t = d.split('/')

        if t in tmap:
            t = str("1" + t)

        # print(f"Initializing BOUNCERS for {n} attempts in {t} seconds")
        BOUNCERS[d] = {
            "memory": ExpiringDict(max_len=10000, max_age_seconds=int(t[:-1]) * tmap[t[-1]]),
            "loginlimit": int(n),
        }


def throttled_login(username):
    # query BOUNCERS for user if user is not in BOUNCERS, add user to BOUNCERS
    # check if user has exceeded attempts return False
    LIMIT_REACHED = False
    for k, v in BOUNCERS.items():
        if username not in v["memory"]:
            v["memory"][username] = 1
            print(f"{username} attempted login {v['memory'][username]} times in {k}")

        else:
            print(f"{username} attempted login {v['memory'][username]} times in {k}")
            if v["memory"][username] > v["loginlimit"]:
                LIMIT_REACHED = True
            v["memory"][username] += 1

    if LIMIT_REACHED:
        return {"status": 429, "message": "Too many requests, retry after some time"}
    else:
        return simulate_login(username)


def simulate_login(username):
    # Simulate a successful login for demonstration purposes
    return "Login Success"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_bouncers(THROTTLE_CONDITIONS)

    for i in range(1000):
        print(throttled_login("user123"))
```

### Output

```
user123 attempted login 1 times in 3/m
user123 attempted login 1 times in 6/10m
user123 attempted login 1 times in 10/30m
Login Success
user123 attempted login 1 times in 3/m
user123 attempted login 1 times in 6/10m
user123 attempted login 1 times in 10/30m
Login Success
user123 attempted login 2 times in 3/m
user123 attempted login 2 times in 6/10m
user123 attempted login 2 times in 10/30m
Login Success
user123 attempted login 3 times in 3/m
user123 attempted login 3 times in 6/10m
user123 attempted login 3 times in 10/30m
Login Success
user123 attempted login 4 times in 3/m
user123 attempted login 4 times in 6/10m
user123 attempted login 4 times in 10/30m
{'status': 429, 'message': 'Too many requests, retry after some time'}
user123 attempted login 5 times in 3/m
user123 attempted login 5 times in 6/10m
user123 attempted login 5 times in 10/30m
{'status': 429, 'message': 'Too many requests, retry after some time'}
```

Comment: It looks it does the same than  https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban ?

Comment: @GuillaumeLebreton yes, fail2ban works at os firewall level and keeps out bots trying to bruteforce. the code i wrote is at the application level, an OS can have N applications running however universal logic is to limit excess activity to one bad actor.
i would suggest look into "nginx zones for rate limiting" its implemented in C and is order magnitude faster.